# Convert pcap text file to csv in Bash

Tags: bash, csv, database-design, datatable, pcap

The content in the text files have the following formats:

```
|1=X1|2=Y1|3=K1|4=J1|5=S1|
|1=X2|3=K2|4=J2|5=S2|
|1=X3|2=Y3|4=J3|5=S3|
...
```

So sometimes it appears there are missing data and what we want is a csv file like the follows:

```
1,2,3,4,5
X1,Y1,K1,J1,S1
X1,,K2,J2,S2
X3,Y3,,J3,S3
...
```

I really have no clues on how to do it with a Bash, regarding the missing data.
There are around 5 million lines with 30+ columns and my idea was we might need to do 30x "if clause" to check and fill out ",," for any missing data. This sounds impractical and apparently there should be better methods.

Comment: read the [awk tutorial](https://gyrmoire.com/Unix/Awk.html), make an attempt to solve your problem, and edit your Q to show your best attempt to solve this. Then we can help you fix your problem. As is, the conditions you add to your problem in the last paragarph  are too broad. Something like `awk '-F=' -vOFS="," '{gsub("|","",$0); print $1, $3, $5"\n" $2, $4, $6\n"}' file` will be something to experiement with. Also, as mentioned below, given only 5 million lines, I wouldn't spend time trying to split up the data. This should run in less than a minute. Good luck.

Comment: This looks helpful.
Indeed the major issue I was stuck at is how to handle the missing data. I am familiar with awk but I am not sure how to recognize the occasionally missing value and do this ',,'
Let me try to implement that! Thank you very much! It would be great if it completes in less than a minute! Thanks for the estimate

Comment: Looks the link is invalid?

Answer (score 1):

You can either use `tshark`, or use [this](https://github.com/vnetman/pcap2csv) program.

```
pip3 install scapy pyshark
python3 pcap2csv --pcap inp.pcap --csv op.csv
```

This should work.

Comment: Link only solutions to problems are not considered good "form" for StackOverflow. This isn't an BBS, it's meant to be a collectoin of self-contained Questions and working Answers. If you edit your answer to include the relevant information from the supplied link, then I can remove my downvote. You **can** leave the link in as a reference, but it shouldn't be given to the O.P. as "the answer".....

Comment: Also, I'd have to take exception with your advise to split the data into 5000 lines. maybe 500000, but modern hardware can write approximately 1GB output per minute, so IMHO, that should be the baseline for designing a data filter. There may be reasons to split up files very small for fast processing, but managing 100s of small files will cost more time unless they are really needed. Good luck to all.

Comment: Oops, I have to type that in by had each time and I forgot to dbl-check I had it right. Try this : http://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . (I didn't downvote your Q by the way). Good luck.